# How to grep for file within a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to grep for the contents of a file within another file.  I'll illustrate by example.  Here is parent.txt:

```
# parent.txt
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

And here is child1.txt:

```
def
ghi
```

And here is child2.txt:

```
jkl
mno
```

And here is child3.txt

```
abc
ghi
```

What I basically want to do is use 'grep -q' to find which child files are within the parent file.  child1.txt's check should return true because it is a whole match.  child2.txt's check should return false because it is only a partial match.  child3.txt should return false as well because the match must be cohesive.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "cohesive"?

Comment: It would appear he means literal match. That is exactly as written in the child file. (Not split over a non-matching line as `child3.txt`'s contents are.)

Comment: Etan Reisner is exactly right.  That is what I meant by cohesive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `diff`, `grep`, and `wc`, you can get what you want.

```
count=$(diff parent.txt child1.txt | grep '^>' | wc -l)
if [[ $count > 0 ]]; then echo "false"; else echo "true"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr "\n" " " <parent.txt | grep -q "$(tr "\n" " " <child1.txt)" && echo true || echo false
tr "\n" " " <parent.txt | grep -q "$(tr "\n" " " <child2.txt)" && echo true || echo false
tr "\n" " " <parent.txt | grep -q "$(tr "\n" " " <child3.txt)" && echo true || echo false
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash pattern matching:

```
parent_contents=$(< parent.txt)
for child in child*.txt; do 
    if [[ "$parent_contents" == *"$(< "$child" )"* ]]; then
        echo $child is cohesively contained in parent
    else
        echo $child is not
    fi
done
```

```
child1.txt is cohesively contained in parent
child2.txt is not
child3.txt is not
```

Encapsulating in a function:

```
cohesively_contains() {
    local parent=$(< "$1")
    local child=$(< "$2")
    [[ "$parent" == *"$child"* ]]
}
for child in child*.txt; do 
    cohesively_contains parent.txt "$child" && echo true || echo false
done
```

```
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk it is much simpler:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a)' parent.txt child1.txt

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a)' parent.txt child2.txt
mno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
{
    if (NR == FNR) {
        a[$0] = FNR
        b[FNR] = $0
    } else if (FNR == 1) {
        if (!(p = a[$0]))
            nextfile
    } else if ($0 != b[++p]) {
        p = 0
        nextfile
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    if (p)
        print FILENAME
}
```

Usage:

```
gawk -f script.awk parent.txt child1.txt child2.txt child3.txt
```

Output:

```
child1.txt
```

With

```
ENDFILE {
    print FILENAME (p ? ": true" : ": false")
}
```

Output:

```
child1.txt: true
child2.txt: false
child3.txt: false
```